# PrimeFaces - Failed to load resource

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I've looked on similar questions and none of the solutions worked.

I'm doing a Ajax call but my method is never called.

I have this error on Chrome:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ERP.GUI2/views/user/login.html  jquery.js.html:23
b.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js.html:23
b.extend.ajax jquery.js.html:23
PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.offer primefaces.js.html:1
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest primefaces.js.html:1
PrimeFaces.ab primefaces.js.html:1
onclick
```

I have checked and those files are ok, they exist and the path is correct, I can open them on the browser.

Here is my button:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{userController.logIn()}" value="Entrar"/>
```

There are times when the error is just:

```
Failed to load resource http://localhost:8080/ERP.GUI2/views/user/login.html
```

When I first run the code, no errors are reported, the error shows exactly when I click the button calling the method.

I don't know if it is important but I'm using Eclipse and it have added a `JavaScript Resources`, I don't know if it is interfering in something and don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JSF ManagedBean annotation or any JSF scope annotation like `@RequestScoped` or `@SessionScoped`, make sure it imports from `javax.faces.bean` package.

Sometimes code completion imports from the wrong package by mistake.

Now, assuming that your `logIn()` method is `public void` as in:

```
public void logIn() 
{
    //login code here 
}
```

you should remove the parenthesis from EL because the actionListener property already expects a method expression.

Try:

`<p:commandButton actionListener="#{userController.logIn}" value="Entrar"/>`

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain me why is there a difference when I'm using Eclipse or NetBeans in this case? If I'm not wrong, Eclipse generate the parenthesis automatically but NetBeans doesn't. Judging by the solution, it is correct **not** to use them, right?

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes, by default, in most situations, you won't use them for method expressions. I used both IDE's and from my experience the Netbeans support for Java EE in general is better.